Cannot create property 'lastUpdateCheck' on string 'lastUpdateCheck 1713521810483 nodeLinker node-modules ces nodeLinker node-modules'
Got this error after installing the node_modules.
TypeError: Cannot create property 'lastUpdateCheck' on string 'lastUpdateCheck 1713521810483 nodeLinker node-modules ces nodeLinker node-modules'
    at /Users/vijayalakshmi/Desktop/e-com/ECommerceApp/.yarn/releases/yarn-1.22.22.cjs:100249:32
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at step (/Users/vijayalakshmi/Desktop/e-com/ECommerceApp/.yarn/releases/yarn-1.22.22.cjs:310:30)
    at /Users/vijayalakshmi/Desktop/e-com/ECommerceApp/.yarn/releases/yarn-1.22.22.cjs:328:14
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at new F (/Users/vijayalakshmi/Desktop/e-com/ECommerceApp/.yarn/releases/yarn-1.22.22.cjs:25832:28)
    at /Users/vijayalakshmi/Desktop/e-com/ECommerceApp/.yarn/releases/yarn-1.22.22.cjs:307:12
    at YarnRegistry.saveHomeConfig (/Users/vijayalakshmi/Desktop/e-com/ECommerceApp/.yarn/releases/yarn-1.22.22.cjs:100253:7)
    at /Users/vijayalakshmi/Desktop/e-com/ECommerceApp/.yarn/releases/yarn-1.22.22.cjs:7440:38
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)

"react": "18.2.0",
"react-native": "0.74.0",
Now using node v18.17.1 (npm v9.6.7)
Tried upgrading the node version to v19, still getting this error.


Open your terminal and enter nano ~/.yarnrc to open the file.
Remove "ces" using the arrow keys.
Press Ctrl+X to exit, then press Y to confirm the changes and hit Enter.


This may be worth trying:
1. Clean yarn cache
yarn cache clean

2. Delete node modules and reinstall
rm -rf node_modules
yarn install

Or, alternatively, try switching to npm or pnpm to see if this error has been resolved. If yes, it's worth looking into your version and configuration of yarn.
Also, please share your package.json, I will then try to install it locally and see what might be the problem.
